# How to generate Calendars in java?

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I need to build a backend Java class that generates Calenders. The Calendar has 12 months to complete a year. In that year, the first month is July and the last month is June. In a sense, the months in the generated calender will have a different years. For instance, the first month will be July-2016 and the last month will be June-2017 and so on. Below is what I have so far.

```
public class Calendars {

    public Date startDate;
    public Date endDate;
    public String periodName;//This is the name of the year(e.g July-2016 to June-2017 may be called period01)
    public short physicalYear;//This is the normal year

    public Calendars() {
    }

    public Calendars(Date startDate, Date endDate, String periodName, short physicalYear) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.periodName = periodName;
        this.physicalYear = physicalYear;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getPeriodName() {
        return periodName;
    }

    public void setPeriodName(String periodName) {
        this.periodName = periodName;
    }

    public short getPhysicalYear() {
        return physicalYear;
    }

    public void setPhysicalYear(short physicalYear) {
        this.physicalYear = physicalYear;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Calendars{" +
                "startDate=" + startDate +
                ", endDate=" + endDate +
                ", periodName='" + periodName + '\'' +
                ", physicalYear=" + physicalYear +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to create a method that can do what's on the paragraph above. I don't have an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: The requirements are very unclear. In a sense, your `Calendars` class is already fulfilling what you are say you want, so no doubt there are some additional requirements that you have not told us?

Comment: What Java version are you using? If you can use Java 8, drop the use of `Date` completely. Look into `YearMonth` or `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.JULY )
         .plusYears( 1 )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`. They are troublesome, confusing, poorly designed, and flawed. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `YearMonth`

You seem to want to track a span of time as whole months. For that use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Note that unlike the legacy classes, in java.time the months have sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.

```
YearMonth start = YearMonth.of( 2017 , 7 );
YearMonth stop = start.plusYears( 1 );
```

Or specify the month using the handy [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
YearMonth start = YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.JULY );
```

If you want the current `YearMonth`, specify a time zone. Remember that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone, and therefore the month may vary.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z );
```

## `LocalDate`

To work with individual dates, use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate dayAfter = firstOfMonth.plusDays( 1 );
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).